# Update field that have duplicates on another table

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table of scores with a foreign key TeamID

```
ID     TeamID    Score   Month
1      1         100     1
2      2         90      2
3      2         80      3
```

And on table Team there are duplicates like this:

```
ID     TeamName
1      Team A
2      Team A
```

I want to update TeamID field on the score table to the first occurence on team table so I can safely delete duplicates on team table, for example to something like this:

```
ID     TeamID    Score   Month
1      1         100     1
2      1         90      2
3      1         80      3
```

any ideas how to do that without manually updating for each ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.id, t2.id as newId
from team t1 
     join (select min(id) as id, 
                 TeamName 
           from team
           group by TeamName) t2 on t1.TeamName=t2.TeamName
```

The query will return you which id should be replaced with new one. Use it in the score table to update ids

Comment: thanks, this is what I need though not exactly updating directly with query. btw I added 'where t1.id != t2.id' at the end so the ones already pointing to first occurence don't show up

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE score SET TeamID = (SELECT ID from Team ORDER BY ID limit 1);
```

Comment: I think you need to join back the Team table with score table with TeamID, then only limit 1.

Comment: This would set all TeamIDs to the same value, independent of the team name.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
UPDATE scores SET TeamID = (SELECT MIN(t3.ID) from Team t2 JOIN Team t3 ON t2.TeamName = t3.TeamName WHERE t2.ID = scores.TeamID)
```